# Load List Item Ribbon tab on page load when using Page in Pages Library

Tags: 2010, ribbon, custom-actions

My question is a little bit different than the other missing / loading ribbon questions and I'll explain why.

In order to properly style my application, I've created a page in the Pages Library and added my existing list onto that page. I didn't want to customize the actual forms within the list.   I want to have the List Ribbon (which I've customized using CustomActions) always open and available on my page (set as my homepage) which is in the Pages Library.

I've tried the InitialTabId but what it does is on page load and it shows for a split second then disappears. I guess this is because the Existing List web part is not selected.

Should I maybe inject some script that selects the webpart?

Answer (score 0):

[There is a bit of code here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73174/items-and-list-tabs-in-ribbon-dont-show-after-editing-page) which aids in showing the "items" and "page" tab once you've edited a list-holding page.  Those tabs become hidden once you edit the page, and the snippet revives them (sort of - it's not perfect).

Maybe you could use that code to help you with your ribbon problem.